# Ruby Parallel each loop

Tags: ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a the following code:

```
FTP ... do |ftp| 
  files.each do |file| 
  ...
  ftp.put(file)
  sleep 1
  end 
end
```

I'd like to run the each file in a separate thread or some parallel way. What's the correct way to do this? Would this be right?

Here's my try on the [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel)

```
FTP ... do |ftp| 
  Parallel.map(files) do |file| 
  ...
  ftp.put(file)
  sleep 1
  end 
end
```

The issue with parallel is puts/outputs can occur at the same time like so:

```
as = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
results = Parallel.map(as) do |a|
  puts a
end
```

How can I force puts to occur like they normally would line separated.

Comment: Usually I use [threach](https://github.com/billdueber/threach), which uses SizedQueues hence allows you to execute a maximum amount of parallel jobs at time (peach does it too)

Comment: I just tried [parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) looks but not sure if it works correctly yet.

Comment: parallel seems nice, I didn't know it, thank you

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of parallelization is to run at the same time. But if there's some part of the process that you'd like to run some of the code sequentially you could use a `mutex` like:

```
semaphore = Mutex.new
as = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
results = Parallel.map(as, in_threads: 3) do |a|
  # Parallel stuff
  sleep rand
  semaphore.synchronize {
    # Sequential stuff
    puts a
  }
  # Parallel stuff
  sleep rand
end
```

You'll see that it prints stuff correctly but not necesarily in the same order. I used `in_threads` instead of `in_processes` (default) because `Mutex` doesn't work with processes. See below for an alternative if you do need processes.

**References:**

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html
- http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/01/28/efficient-cross-processing-locking-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of keeping it simple, here's what I'd do with built-in `Thread`:

```
results = files.map do |file|
  result = Thread.new do
    ftp.put(file)
  end
end
```

Note that this code assumes that `ftp.put(file)` returns safely. If that isn't guaranteed, you'll have to do that yourself by wrapping calls in a timeout block and have each thread return an exception if one is thrown and then at the very end of the loop have a blocking check to see that `results` does not contain any exceptions.